# Создание БД у пользователя

Tags: java, база-данных, windows, postgresql

Я делаю приложение, которое позволяет сохранить информацию о ставках пользователя в журнал (БД PostgreSQL). На моём компьютере установлен SQL сервер и разумеется всё работает.
Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь открывает приложение, создавалась БД на его компьютере?

Comment: Зачем ему там бд? С какой целью вы хотите этого?

Comment: По сути СУБД это отдельное приложение. А не просто файл. Так вот когда запускается приложение вам нужно чтоб появилась база. А она сама по себе не появится.

Comment: Хранить информацию о ставках. С возможностью редактирования

Comment: В файл обычный пишите. И редактируйте хоть до пасхи

Comment: Я понимаю. Хотел узнать как её можно поставлять вместе с приложением или же после его запуска как-то устанавливать её.

Comment: Если нет промышленных данных то и надобности нет в промышленной субд

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Это называется продакшн. И его отдельно настраивают обычно

Comment: Попробуйте использовать H2 или sqlite

Comment: Просто вместо отдельной СУБД используйте встраиваемую, например очень популярную SQLite или другие, типа PouchDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну установка и настройка СУБД для непонимающего пользователя дело такое, нетривиальное.

Я вижу два решения вашей проблемы, исходя из описанных условий

1. Вместо PostgreSQL используйте что-то встраиваемое. Например SQLite3, раз уж вам SQL-решение по душе, отличная БД. Встраивается на уровне кода, создается при выполнении, если нужно. Ничего, кроме вашего приложения конечному пользователю уже не нужно ставить, так как для использования к приложении приложится библиотечка с реализацией этой БД. Или даже вшить можно в бинарник (я не знаю как там в Java, можно ли так упаковать приложение "все-в-одно", но наверное можно).
2. Если БД какая то централизованная, то зачем создавать ее у пользователя, если можно просто настроить удаленный доступ к ней? То есть вы хостите свою БД где-то на сервере, а пользователи к ней подключаются. Либо напрямую (что наверное не очень хорошо), либо через какой-нибудь REST API (что лучше с точки зрения безопасности, гибкости и масштабирования).

Comment: Посмотрю в сторону SQLite. Так как информация требуется только одному пользователю, то смысла в централизованной БД нет.